# How to get the dynamic port number in Java for Socket client

Tags: java, sockets

I try to find out how to get the Portnumber for a Socket dynamic.

```
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(0);
System.out.println("listening on port: " + s.getLocalPort())
```

I found this example on StackOverflow. It works but I do not need a ServerSocket. I need a Socket:

```
Socket s = new Socket("http://www.google.at", 8081);
System.out.println("listening on port: " + s.getLocalPort())
```

I was searching with google and did not find the Solution. Maybe one can help me. I am sure there is a way to get the Portnumber for Socket Dynamic. But I could not find it on StackOverflow and on google.

I already try this one:

```
Socket s = new Socket("http://www.google.at", 0);
System.out.println("listening on port: " + s.getLocalPort())
```

greetings
Christoph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already found the solution. `Socket.getLocalPort()` gets you the local port of a `Socket`. Strangely enough. If you haven't bound that `Socket`, as here, or bound it to port zero, the local port is allocated dynamically.

`new Socket("...", 0)` (a) is illegal and (b) would constitute an attempt to connect to a dynamic *remote* port, if it was legal, which it isn't.

Why you need to know the local port of a `Socket` is another question.

NB `ServerSockets` listen. `Sockets` connect.

Comment: I have to write a Proxy Server for the university. Its my First time using Java for this. I have in my Solution now a localport which is the Port on that the Client can connect to my Proxy Server (I choosed 8080). Then I have to open a Connection from the Server to the Website and pass all the content. Therefor I need a remote Port. In all solutions I found they used Socket("Adress", port"). So That what I have to do is, to creat another ServerSocket and then use this port for the Connection with Socket. Well I thank you. Learned Something over both classes :-)

Comment: So you have to know the remote port you need to connect to. Nothing dynamic about that, and nothing local about it either. It is the port on which the remote website is listening, almost certainly one of 80, 443, 8080, or 8443. Or possibly it is supplied by the client. You do not have to create another `ServerSocket`.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/Asimpleproxyserver.htm This is the Example they gave us and telling us this is the way to do it. So I see there a remoteport. So the remoteport is not the port I have on the Server it is the Port the Server I want to connect is listening? So the task is to find out on which port the Server I want to connect is listening and then use this port?

Comment: The remote port is the one you connect to with the second parameter of `new Socket(...)`. It is either fixed or supplied by the client, as I've already stated. Either you haven't been given enough information to execute this assignment or you haven't read it. In the linked code, `remotePort` is 100. Not dynamic. And there is no second `SsrverSocket` there either.

Comment: Thank you :-) I got a much better understanding. I think I know now what I have to do! And I think I found something on google maybe helping me. I think i use the class URLConnection. I am not allowed to use httpURLConnection but URLConnection ist fine.